# How to two used while Syntax in Mysql Procecure

Tags: mysql, while-loop, procedure

I would like to write two While Syntax.

The results I expect are as follows.

when 'H' 
  tagName1, tagName2, tagname3 
when 'D' 
  tagName1, tagName2, tagname3 
when 'M' 
  tagName1, tagName2, tagname3 
when 'Y' 
  tagName1, tagName2, tagname3

But it didn't worked....

Below is the code that I wrote, while I play it only once.

Any advice, please..

```
DECLARE tagList varchar(255) DEFAULT 'tagName1,tagName2,tagName3';
DECLARE tagTypeList varchar(150) DEFAULT 'H,D,M,Y';
WHILE tagTypeList != '' DO
 WHILE tagList != '' DO  
    SET tagNameArray = SUBSTRING_INDEX(tagList, ',', 1);
    SET tagTypeArray = SUBSTRING_INDEX(tagTypeList, ',', 1);    

 IF(tagTypeArray = 'H') THEN
        SET aDate = (SELECT (DATE_ADD(nDateTime, INTERVAL -1 HOUR)));
        SET ago_Y = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%Y'));
        SET ago_M = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%m'));
        SET ago_D = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%d'));
        SET ago_H = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%H'));
        SET ago_W = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%w'));

 ELSEIF(tagTypeArray = 'D') THEN
        SET aDate = (SELECT (DATE_ADD(nDateTime, INTERVAL -1 DAY)));
        SET ago_Y = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%Y'));
        SET ago_M = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%m'));
        SET ago_D = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%d'));

        SET ago_H = 0;
        SET ago_W = 0;

 ELSEIF(tagTypeArray = 'M')  THEN
        SET aDate = (SELECT (DATE_ADD(nDateTime, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)));
        SET ago_Y = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%Y'));
        SET ago_M = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%m'));

        SET ago_D = 0;
        SET ago_H = 0;
        SET ago_W = 0;

 ELSEIF(tagTypeArray = 'Y')   THEN
        SET aDate = (SELECT (DATE_ADD(nDateTime, INTERVAL -1 YEAR)));
        SET ago_Y = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%Y'));
        SET ago_M = 0;
        SET ago_D = 0;
        SET ago_H = 0;
        SET ago_W = 0;          
 END IF;


   SET selectValue = (SELECT tagvalue FROM datasource WHERE tagname = tagNameArray and tagtype = tagTypeArray and y=ago_Y and m=ago_M and d=ago_D and h=ago_H);

   IF(selectValue IS NULL OR selectValue = '')
        THEN

            SET old_Value_3M = (Select LastValue from BwAnalogTable where TagName = tagNameArray and LogDate >= ago_3M order by LogDate desc, LogTime desc limit 1);
           # Here Insert Querty
   END IF;     



    IF LOCATE(',', tagList) > 0 THEN        
      SET tagList = SUBSTRING(tagList, LOCATE(',', tagList) + 1);
    ELSE
      SET tagList = '';
    END IF; 
 END WHILE;


    IF LOCATE(',', tagTypeList) > 0 THEN
      SET tagTypeList = SUBSTRING(tagTypeList, LOCATE(',', tagTypeList) + 1);
   ELSE
      SET tagTypeList = '';
   END IF;
END WHILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code as shown below.

```
DECLARE done  INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE tagType2 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE tagName2 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE tagType_Cur CURSOR for select tagType from tbtagtype;
DECLARE tagName_Cur CURSOR for select tagName from tbtaglist;

 OPEN tagType_Cur;
         LOOP1: LOOP
                FETCH tagType_Cur INTO tagType2;                    
                IF done THEN                             
                       CLOSE tagType_Cur;
                       LEAVE LOOP1;
                END IF; 
           ########## here insert your core query ###############              
         OPEN tagName_Cur;
                LOOP2: LOOP
                    FETCH tagName_Cur INTO tagName2;

                    IF done THEN
                         CLOSE tagName_Cur;
                         SET done = FALSE;
                         LEAVE LOOP2;
                    END IF;
                    ########## here insert your core query ###############  
                  END LOOP LOOP2;                    
         END LOOP LOOP1;
```